# Misaligned columns in Pandas dataframe from pandas.ExcelFile import

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have an Excel spreadsheet that contains some transactional data. I tried importing it into a Pandas dataframe:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> xlsfile = pd.ExcelFile("/data/transactions.xls")
>>> data = xlsfile.parse('data')
```

... and, at first glance, it looked OK. Then I noticed that a column (i.e. 'Ship To Region') that should contain one of four possible values:

[image]

... often had values that didn't make sense. Although the values, for the most part, end up in the correct columns, there are thousands of instances where this was not the case:

```
>>> len(data['Ship To Region'].unique())
5007
```

Values from neighboring cells are somehow creeping into the wrong columns.

```
>>> for value in data['Ship To Region'].unique():
...     print value
...

Americas
EMEA
APAC
nan
Ship To Name
Justin Bieber
Marie Curie Industries
BKS Iyengar
[...etc...]
```

Can you see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: try parsing with  xlrd? can you maybe use CSV instead?

Comment: Thanks @smushi. I tried saving the spreadsheet as a CSV and using Pandas' `pd.read_csv()` though, unfortunately, I got the same result. I'll probably end up using `xlrd` or `openpyxl` as an intermediate step though that does feel like a bit of a kludge.

Answer (score 0):

That is certainly strange.  What version of Pandas are you using?

By the way, you can use pd.read_excel() and do that all in one line.

Comment: Thanks @BobHaffner. I'm using Pandas version 0.14.1. I did try `pd.read_excel()` and got the same result, though I agree that it's more Pythonic.

Comment: Ok,the only advice i have for you is to upgrade Pandas.  Sorry, not much help.

Comment: Appreciate the suggestions, @BobHaffner. I just upgraded Pandas to 0.15.1 but still experienced the same behavior.

Comment: In the end the inconsistency between Pandas and Excel was caused by discontinuous data in the Excel spreadsheet. The list of values shown in the Excel filter wasn't being populated by the entire sheet, whereas Pandas was scanning all the rows.

Comment: Wow, that was an evil one.  :-)    Thanks for the followup